# How to check data from mysql realtime using ajax post requests?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to check data from mysql realtime using ajax post requests ?

I use this code for check in mysql , if user have a new message it's will be echo `YOU HAVE NEW MESSAGE` text on realtime.

and this code will post to `get_data.php` every 1 sec , i think it's very work hard for server and client ,

when i try it's not work, How can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="idForm"/>
    <input name="uid" value="1234"/>
</form>
<div id="result_data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: get_data.php,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $('#result_data').show();
           }
         });
    },1000);    
});
</script>
```

Comment: hello, you will have to do this kind of stuff by using websockets... its protocol overhead is way smaller than HTTP since its closer to TCP - easiest way to do this is check out socket.io framework > if you have any questions related to this feel free to ask me!

Answer (score 0):

Your best practice would be to go with WebSockets.
The protocol overhead is much smaller than HTTP and you will play PING and PONG with the server to check for new data.

With websockets your client could send a message by emitting data your server would receive this and e.g. broadcast it out to other clients.

Try to get your head in Socket.io that is what I did to understand this ;)

Comment: facebook use  WebSockets ? for alert a new message.

Comment: yes, every realtime service uses WebSockets... you can check that for yourself by clicking f12 in your browser and looking at the network connection

Comment: but WebSockets not work on ie7 , why when i use facebook on ie7, Why message alert function are work?

Comment: I go with the compromise that if you want modern technology you will also have to adapt to it... so screw IE7

Answer (score 0):

Asumming your php file is correct, it might help if you wait for your document to be ready in your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Your code
});
```

It's a minor thing but sometimes it break scripts